# Convert from String to DateTime in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I have a variable called workFrom that has time(hh:mm) as String at the FrontEnd(Angular JS). I would like to convert this to Date format before posting the data on to MongoDB with default date as 01/01/1970 and the time from whatever has been posted from workFrom. How do I do it?

Eg : workFrom : 11:40 should be converted to 01/01/1970 11:40 (according to the standard format of date used in MongoDB).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) package to parse and validate dates.

Comment: I am a newbie to Node JS, So could you be more elaborate on how to convert  @abhishekkannojia

Comment: You don't need a library: `'11:40'.split(':').reduce((h,m)=> new Date(h*3.6e6 + m*6e4).toISOString())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution in vanila JS.

```js
var input = '11:40';
var parts = input.split(':');
var minutes = parts[0]*60 +parts[1];
var inputDate = new Date(minutes * 60 * 1000);
console.log(inputDate);
```

Or use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) as wrote abhishekkannojia.

Comment: I think you need `parts[0]*60 + +parts[1]` but otherwise, great.

Comment: First operand `parts[0]*60` is number, then second operand `parts[1]` will be converted to number

Comment: No, it won't. While `parts[1]*60` returns a number, `parts[0]` is a string, so it will be concatenated, not added. And you have the indices reversed, you want `parts[0]*60`, etc. Those two errors mean the value of *minutes* is `"240011"` instead of `700` and the result is `"1970-06-16T16:11:00.000Z"` instead of `"1970-01-01T11:40:00Z"`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach can be like this:

```
workFrom = "11:40";
time = new Date("01/01/1970" + " " + workFrom);
console.log(time.getDate() +'/'+ time.getMonth() +'/'+ ime.getFullYear()+ ' '+ time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 1):

With using moment (Which I recomend whenever you are dealing with date/time related problems):

```
let workFrom = "11:40";
let workFromMoment = moment(workFrom,'hh:mm')  
let adjustedMoment = moment([1970,0,1]).hour(workFromMoment.hour()).minute(workFromMoment.minute())
let dateString = adjustedMoment.format('D/M/Y hh:mm')`
console.log(dateString);
```

This snippet, in turn, will produce the output of "1/1/1970 11:40"

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date("01/01/1970 11:40:0:0");
```

you can do it:

```
 date="01/01/1970";
 workFrom="11:40";
 d = new Date(date +" "+workFrom);
```

Comment: Parsing strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is strongly discouraged.